# What does the 0 stand for at the end of the text which os.system() returns?

Tags: python, python-os

What does that 0 at the end of the output stand for?

[image: screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Look into the descriction of what the command does that you use... you print its returned value...

Comment: Instead of posting pictures of text, post the text.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I'm new here :)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) returns the exit status of the process you executed. Since the `cat` command succeeded, it's exit code is 0, and that's what you see from `print(x)`.